# DROPDOWN list input values not fetched

Tags: php, html, yii

I get repeatedly the same error. dropdown data is not fetched from the form. I have my code here

this is my controller:ProductController

```
{<?php

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new CreateForm;
    // collect user input data
        if(isset($_POST['CreateForm']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['CreateForm'];
                        $model->setAttributes($_POST['CreateForm']);
            // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
            if($model->validate())
                        { 
                        $product=new Product;
                        $product->save();
                        }
                        else {
                            echo "Hi";
                        }
        }
        // display the login form
        $this->render('create',array('model'=>$model));


    }
}
?>}
```

My model:CreateForm

```
 {<?php

    class CreateForm extends CFormModel
    {
        public $product_name;
        public $category_name;
        public $description;


        public function rules()
        {
            return array(
                array('product_name, category_name, description', 'required'),
               array('product_name', 'unique', 'className' => 'Product', 'attributeName' => 'product_name', 'message'=>'This product name is already in use'),
            );

        }

        public function attributeLabels()
        {
            return array(
                'product_name'=>'PRODUCT NAME',
                        'category_name'=>'CATEGORY',
                        'description'=>'DESCRIPTION'
            );
        }



    }
    ?>

}
```

Category

```
{
<?php
class Category extends CActiveRecord
{
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'category';
    }

   public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'category_id'=>'CATEGORY ID',
                    'category_name'=>'CATEGORY NAME',

        );
    }    
}
?>}
```

MY view:create.php

```
{<?php
$this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name . ' - Create';
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Create',
);
?>

<h1>CREATE</h1>
<div class="form">
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'create-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,

)); 

?>


    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'product_name'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'product_name'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'product_name'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <?php
             echo $form->labelEx($model,'category_name');   
                $records = Category::model()->findAll();
               $list = CHtml::listData($records, 'category_id', 'category_name');
                echo CHtml::DropDownList('category_name', null, $list, array('prompt'=>'select '));
               echo $form->error($model,'category_name');
                ?>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'description'); ?></br>
        <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'description',array('style' => 'height:100px;width:500px;','maxlength'=>500)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'description'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row submit">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('CREATE'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div><!-- form -->
}
```

if I enter all the fields, again it gives an error stating "PLS enter the category"

Comment: Have you defined the safe attributes in the model's rules function?

Comment: yes added. { public function rules()
    {
        return array(
   array('product_name, category_name, description', 'required'),
           array('product_name', 'unique', 'className' => 'Product', 'attributeName' => 'product_name', 'message'=>'This product name is already in use'),
 array('product_name,category_name,desc', 'safe'), 
            );
        
    }}

Comment: Also is the DropDownList tied to the model, or sending its param "bare"?

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is called massive assignment

```
$model->attributes=$_POST['CreateForm'];
```

this would not assign all the values and is not safe in handling datas also

the datas would be saved only if they are in safe in the model

you will redeclare the posted data as

```
$model->attributes=$_POST['CreateForm'];
$model->dropdownname=$_POST['CreateForm']['dropdownname'];
```

Hope this will help you

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/161/understanding-safe-validation-rules/#hh2

Answer (score 0):

I think you change your code of dropdown.

```
<?php
echo $form->labelEx($model,'category_name');   
$records = Category::model()->findAll();
$list = CHtml::listData($records, 'category_id', 'category_name');
echo CHtml::DropDownList('category_name', null, $list, array('prompt'=>'select '));
echo $form->error($model,'category_name');
?>
```

To

```
<?php
echo $form->labelEx($model,'category_name');   
$records = Category::model()->findAll();
$result = array();
foreach($records as $p) {
  $result[p->category_id] = p->category_name ;     
}
echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model, 'category_name', $result);
echo $form->error($model,'category_name');
?>
```

Now you need to check, either your category id or name is coming or not. 
Then you debug your controller file, as in given below.

```
public function actionCreate()
{
  $model=new CreateForm;
  // collect user input data
  if(isset($_POST['CreateForm']))
  {
  $model->attributes=$_POST['CreateForm'];

  echo $model->category_id ;
  exit ; // Finish program here, and drop down will be printed.  

  $model->setAttributes($_POST['CreateForm']);
  // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
  if($model->validate())
  { 
  $product=new Product;
  $product->save();
  }
  else {
  echo "Hi";
  }
  }        // display the login form
  $this->render('create',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

Hope it help you.

Thanks